# Gatling - how do I run a particular scenario for a specific duration

Tags: scala, gatling

I have two scenarios which I want to execute in parallel, ramp up and maintain the load for 5 minutes before stopping  the users. similiar to the scheduler in loadrunner.

I have used the below approach, please advice if this is right way of doing it.

```
val BP01AddSearch = scenario("BP01Search").during (5 minutes)
            {
                exec(Homepage.homepage, Login.login, SearchLink.search,  Logout.logout)
            }
        val BP02GASearch = scenario("BP02GASearch").during (5 minutes) {
            exec(Homepage.homepage, Login.login, SearchLink.search, Logout.logout)
        }

setUp(
            BP01AddSearch.inject(rampUsers(5) during (15 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol),
            BP02GASearch.inject(rampUsers(2) during (15 seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol)
        )   .maxDuration(300 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that would work.

Note 1: you can use a `forever` loop instead of a `during` one as you're interrupting with `maxDuration` anyway.

Note 2: if you're setting the same `httpProtocol` on each scenario, you can define it on the `setUp` just like you did for `maxDuration`.

Note 3: you can use `maxDuration(5.minutes)` instead of `maxDuration(300 seconds)`.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane. Much appreciate it. regarding note1 - will maxduration alone work without the .during that I have currently specificed on each scenario.  I tried it and doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: No. `maxDuration` only forces the test to stop when it would normally last longer.